# invalidClassException: please help getting these errors

Tags: java, polymorphism, serializable

I am getting this error when i run the program:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: Food; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1986042743597353721, local class serialVersionUID = -2452322360924937818
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:570)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1599)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1494)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1599)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1494)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1748)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1683)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1321)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    at GroceryStore.readInventory(GroceryStore.java:16)
    at GroceryStore.main(GroceryStore.java:39)
```

I tried so many things but not really sure where im going wrong, im new to this thing.

```
    import java.io.Serializable;

    public abstract class Food implements Serializable {
    String Type, Name;
    double Price;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2452322360924937818L;

    public Food(String Type, String Name, double Price){
            this.Type = Type;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Price = Price;
    }
    public String getType(){
        return Type;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return Name;
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return Price;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return (Type + " " + Name + " " + Price);
    }
    public abstract double getQuantity();
}



    import java.io.Serializable;

    public class FoodItem extends Food implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = -2452322360924937818L;
     private double quantity;
     int bestBeforeMonth;
     int bestBeforeDay;


     public FoodItem(String Type, String Name, double Price, double quantity, int        bestBeforeMonth, int bestBeforeDay) {
        super(Type, Name, Price);
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.bestBeforeDay = bestBeforeDay;
        this.bestBeforeMonth = bestBeforeMonth;
     }


     @Override
     public double getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
     }
     public void removeQuantity(double quantity){
        this.quantity = this.quantity - quantity;
     }

    }


    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;


    public class GroceryStore {
     static FoodItem[] inventory = null; 
     public static void readInventory(){

    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("grocery.bin"));
        inventory[0] =  (FoodItem) in.readObject();



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     }

public static void main(String[] args){
    readInventory();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is coming due to version mismatch between serialized version of the class and current class.

The message is saying the class you have serialized with object stream has version id `-1986042743597353721`,  but your class version id is `-2452322360924937818L`.

So you have 2 options:

- Get the class with serial version id -1986042743597353721, or ...
- Write a custom deserializer which understands the old format and
  can construct a new object.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) is the full documentation.

Comment: Let's say i wanted to go with the -1986042743597353721 class, how do i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your file "grocery.bin" was populated with Food objects created from a Food.class with serialVersionUID = -1986042743597353721 and you are trying to cast it to a Food.class with serialVersionUID = -2452322360924937818

First of all I would try to change the serialVersionUID of your implemented class to -1986042743597353721.

If other related exceptions appear, then there are actual differences from the serialized objects and your class. In this case you should find out who or what created the grocery.bin and clone its Food.java class.

Comment: so where should i change it? in the Food class? or FoodItem class? and is this how to do it private static final long serialVersionUID = -1986042743597353721L;

Comment: Food class, the abstract class. And yes, this is the way to do it.

Comment: I tried that and got this error now. java.io.InvalidClassException: FoodItem; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -2452322360924937818, local class serialVersionUID = 1140335404112415784

Comment: Your FoodItem class has which serialVersionUID? According to the error, it should be -2452322360924937818L